# javascript for each loop wait until process completes ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, for-loop, flickr

```
for (var i = 0; i < theTagNames.length; i++) {
    var url = baseURL + "?" +
        "jsoncallback=?" +
        "&method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos" +
        "&format=json" +
        "&api_key=" + api +
        "&photoset_id=" + theTagNames[i].id;
    tagID = theTagNames[i].id;
    console.log('for: ' + i)

    $.getJSON(url, {}, function (data) {
        tmpSetName = theTagNames[tmpi].title._content;
        category = theTagNames[tmpi].description._content;
        tmpi += 1;
        keepTrack = 0;

        $.each(data.photoset.photo, function (z, item) {
            if (i == limit) return false;
            console.log('each: ' + z)

            var thumbURL = 'http://farm' + item.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + item.server + '/' + item.id + '_' + item.secret + '_s.jpg';
            var largeURL = thumbURL.replace('_s.jpg', '_b.jpg');

            keepTrack = z

            if (keepTrack == 0) {
                $('#flickrImages').append('<div style="float: left;background-color: #102C53; color: #fff; width: 690px; text-align:left; font-weight: bold; padding: 3px;" id="title' + tmpSetName + '">' + tmpSetName +
                    '<span id="span' + tmpSetName.replace(/ /g, '_') + '" style="cursor: pointer; float: right;" onclick="clickedTitle(this);">' +
                    ' [Start Slideshow]' +
                    '</span>' +
                    '</div>');
            }

            if (keepTrack <= (displayLimit - 1)) {
                $('#flickrImages').append('<span align="left" style="float: left;" id="imgDiv">' +
                    '<a style="outline: none;" rel="' + tmpSetName.replace(/ /g, '_') + '" title="" href="' + largeURL + '" id="imgLink' + tmpSetName.replace(/ /g, '_') + i + '">' +
                    '<img id="img' + i + '" src="' + thumbURL + '" style="border: 1px solid #102C53; margin: 3px;" alt="' + tmpSetName + '" />' +
                    '</a>' +
                    '</span>');
            } else if (keepTrack == (displayLimit + 1)) {
                showMoreImages = true;
            } else {
                $('#flickrImages').append('<span align="left" style="float: left; display: none; visibility: hidden;" id="hidden' + tmpSetName.replace(/ /g, '_') + '">' +
                    '<a style="outline: none;" rel="' + tmpSetName.replace(/ /g, '_') + '" title="" href="' + largeURL + '" id="imgLink' + tmpSetName.replace(/ /g, '_') + i + '">' +
                    '<img id="img' + i + '" src="' + thumbURL + '" style="border: 1px solid #102C53; margin: 3px;" alt="' + tmpSetName + '" />' +
                    '</a>' +
                    '</span>');
            }
        });
    });
}
}
```

Currenlty the above code works but when i refresh the page it tends to get the images out of order (wrong heading with the images & also wrong images that go with that heading). It seems to be getting ahead of itself since the **$.each** could have over 50+ images to get *per **theTagName***.

Sometimes its in the correct order but often times it is not.

Is it possible to pause the **for (var i = 0; i < theTagNames.length; i++) {** until all images in the **$.each** have been found and appened to the **flickrImages** div?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceErrors: limit, displayLimit are not defined

Comment: @watson: displayLimit = 16, limit = 99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the whole  `$.getJSON(url, {}, function (data) { ...` in a separate function outside the for loop and then pass in `i` otherwise the value of `i` will change as you have an async situation.

Also, you should use a different variable name for the index parameter of your $.each function.

So your code would look something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < theTagNames.length; i++) {
    // stuff
    getFlkrJSON(data, i);
}

function getFlkrJSON(data, i){
    $.getJSON(url, {}, function (data) {
        //stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: If i put **console.log('for: ' + i)** inside the for and also **console.log('each: ' + i);** inside the $.each i would expect to see it output **for: 0, each: 0, each: 1, each: xx... for: 1, each: 0, each: 1, each: xx...** but it does this: **for: 0, for: 1, for: xx..., each: 0, each: 1, each: xx...**

Comment: i dont really get what your trying to say, but you definitely shouldn't be using the same variable name i in both loops.

Comment: I updated my OP with the console.log that i was talking about. I also changed the **$.each "i"** to z so it would not conflict with the i in the for loop.

Comment: but it still has the same issues even when doing that... it seems to keep looping even though $.getjson has not finished with getting all the images for that given theTagNames.

Comment: @StealthRT yes, that's the intended behavior.

Comment: If you want them to all return in the same order that you execute them, you will ether have to wait for them all to complete and then loop through them again, or send them one at a time.